# How to make a static method in KMM project

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm implementing a library using KMM(Kotlin Multiplatform). And to create an instance of a class I used a static method. However, a static method's not accessible in iOS project. How can I implement it cleanly.

```
expect class Verifier{
    companion object{
        fun getInstance():Verifier
    }
}

// actual implementations
actual class Verifier{
    actual companion object{
        actual fun getInstance():Verifier{
            /// make an instance and return
        }
    }
}
```

And I would like to get an instance of `Verifier` class as the following:

```
// calling in swift
Verifier.getInstance()

// calling in kotlin
Verifier.getInstance()
```

Is it possible to access as above and implement static methods in a shared module.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked lib generated header file for to check how it was generated? I'd expect it to be available with `Verifier.companion.getInstance()`

Comment: Yes, I've checked it and no success so far. Even Verifier.companion.getInstance()'s not available in iOSmain.

Comment: have you found `getInstance` in the header file? I tried adding your code into a newly created project and `Verifier.companion.getInstance()` works fine